# Google maps autocomplete to restrict places shown in a specific country?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am using google maps autocomplete correctly, however I want to restrict all the places shown to a specific country.

What modifications shall I do into the code in order to achieve that?

```
  function initAutocomplete() {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        (document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
        {types: ['geocode']});
  }


  function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geolocation = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          center: geolocation,
          radius: position.coords.accuracy
        });
        autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
      })

;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Have you Googled `Google maps autocomplete to restrict places shown in a specific country`? There seem to be loads of results. Can you clarify how they don't work for you?

Comment: Here's the doc, did you read that? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#add_autocomplete Quote: "Currently, you can use componentRestrictions to filter by up to 5 countries. Countries must be passed as as a two-character, ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2 compatible country code. Multiple countries must be passed as a list of country codes."

Comment: @Pekka웃 the this is that I added `var options = {
  types: ['(cities)'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'}
};` just below the geolocation part, without any luck

Comment: @ChrisG i did, however as written on the above comment, I didn't have any luck

Comment: Can you edit into the code how you did this? Sometimes it's just a question of the parameter being on the wrong nesting level

Comment: @Pekka웃 I have updated my code, thank you

Comment: You don't seem to be using `options` anywhere in the code? You're just creating it. It's supposed to go as a second parameter to `google.maps.places.Autocomplete()`, as shown in the example Chris linked to, no?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the componentRestrictions option to restrict the autocomplete search to a particular country. The following code restricts the results to cities within France.

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {
  types: ['(cities)'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'}
};

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

Comment: Hi I dont clearly understand where to add this. Cn you make it in reference with my example?

Answer (score 0):

just try adding it after '{types:[geocode]}'

```
      autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
    {types: ['geocode'], componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'}});
```